# Fastest way to transmit pixel data over HTTP

Tags: javascript, maps, pixel, data-transfer

I'm developing an app that is basically an infinite mural for users to draw pixel art (http://pixelmural.com/). Users should be able to move around the mural freely, but every time they move, I have to update the pixels they see, and that requires a request to the server to get the pixel data. At first I was transmitting the data as JSON, and it was super slow. Then I switched to PNG, and things got much faster. Now I'm wondering if there is some way to transmit the data even faster, so that moving around would be smoother. I think my problem is similar to that of data transmission when moving around in maps, but unlike maps my info isn't vectors but pixels.

One thing I could still do to improve performance is to only load the new pixels, rather than the whole screen as I'm currently doing. However before I code that, I wanted to ask if there is a better approach altogether. I feel I may be doing it all wrong.

Comment: Maps bitmaps (not vectors) load in **blocks**. Blocks may also be preloaded. Also take a look to web sockets, if you download raw image data you can render blocks pretty fast using a canvas.

Comment: [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)